# Display one question from a table at a time in quiz application django

Tags: django

I have tried a lot but i am not able to display only 1 question at a time in 
quiz application django.

Here is the body of html file

```
<form id="myform" action="/javar/"  method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <center><h1 class ="hone">Welcome {{user.username}}, To Online Quiz</h1></center>
    {% for item in query_results %}
        <div class="question-panel">
            <div class="question" >
                <label class="question-label">{{ item.QUESTION_NO }}</label>
                <b>{{ item.QUESTION }}</b>
            </div>
            <ol  class ="op" type='A'>
                <li ><input type='radio' name="java{{item.QUESTION_NO}}"
 value='1' />{{item.OPTION1}}<br><br></li>
                <li ><input type='radio' name="java{{item.QUESTION_NO}}" value='2' />{{item.OPTION2}}<br><br></li>
                <li ><input type='radio' name="java{{item.QUESTION_NO}}" 
value='3'  />{{item.OPTION3}}<br><br></li>
                <li ><input type='radio' name="java{{item.QUESTION_NO}}" value='4'  />{{item.OPTION4}}<br><br></li>
            </ol>
            <hr/>
        </div>
     <center><input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return 
ValidateForm(this.form)"></center>
</form>
```

Here is models.py

```
class JAVATEST(models.Model):
    QUESTION_NO=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    QUESTION=models.CharField(max_length=300)
    OPTION1=models.CharField(max_length=300)
    OPTION2=models.CharField(max_length=300)
    OPTION3=models.CharField(max_length=300)
    OPTION4=models.CharField(max_length=300)
    ANSWER=models.IntegerField(default=0)


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.QUESTION_NO)+" "+self.QUESTION+" "+self.OPTION1+" 
"+self.OPTION2+" "+self.OPTION3+" "+self.OPTION4+" "+str(self.ANSWER)
```

here is views.py

```
def javaq(request):
    context = {
        'query_results' : JAVATEST.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, 'javaq.html',context)


def javar(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        chosenOption = ''
        correctAns = ''
        c=0
        x=1
        for ans in JAVATEST.objects.all():
            chosenOption=str(request.POST.get("java"+str(x)))
            correctAns=str(ans.ANSWER)
            if chosenOption==correctAns:
                c=c+1
            x=x+1
        article = result()
        article.sid = request.session['sd']
        article.marks = c
        article.subject = 'JAVA'
        article.tdate = str(datetime.datetime.now())
        article.save()    
        context = {
            'query_results1' :c
        }

    return render(request, 'javar.html',context)
```

Pls Help me as i am not able to display single question at a time

Comment: Can you share your models/views/... (other relevant information)?

Answer (score 0):

You are giving all the JAVATEST instances to the template from here

```
def javaq(request):
    context = {
        'query_results' : JAVATEST.objects.all() # <---- 
    }
    return render(request, 'javaq.html',context)
```

Why not just one question? probably keep track of the user attended questions and get one question at a time excluding the ones the user attended.

```
def javaq(request):
    user_attended_questions = # get a list of user attended question ids here
    context = {
        'query_results' : JAVATEST.objects.exclude(id__in=user_attended_questions).first() # excluding the questions user already attended and picking the first question from the remaining queryset 
    }
    return render(request, 'javaq.html',context)
```

Comment: nice idea but can u give me some more details on how to code for it.

Comment: Then my timer will also be affected I hink

Comment: You can create a m2m relation between user and the questions and keep track of the user attended questions. As for the timer, I recommend you to use a lightweight front end framework like Vue.js to handle submitting the question, evaluating, showing the result and finally to get the next question through ajax.